# VBA behaving weirdly, can't get the value stored in variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a very strange problem. I am not able to get the value returned from a simple function as below if the return value is more than one char. Now the second problem is that following code is not assigning "WTH" to sheetName variable. Refer to the screenshot 2. **UPDATED AFTER CYRIL'S COMMENTS**

```
Public Sub WTHFormatter()

    Dim sheetName As String

    sheetName = "WTH"

    Dim rng1 As Range

    'delete empty rows

    lastRowWTH = getLastRow(sheetName, 2)

    'Delete rows below the last Row
    Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(lastRowWTH + 1 & ":" & Worksheets(sheetName).Rows.Count).Delete

    ' build first range

    Set rng1 = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("B11:F" & lastRowWTH)

    Call setCellBorders(rng1)

    Set rng1 = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("H11:K" & lastRowWTH)

    Call setCellBorders(rng1)

    'determine the range for months

    For i = 13 To 24

        If Cells(7, i) = "" Then
            lastCol = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
        lastCol = i
    Next

    ColLetter = returnLabel(lastCol)
    ColLetter2 = returnLabel(lastCol + 2)
    ColLetterX = returnLabel(lastCol + 14)

    Set rng1 = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("K17:" & ColLetter & lastRowWTH)

    Call setCellBorders(rng1)

    Set rng1 = Worksheets(sheetName).Range(ColLetter2 & lastRowWTH & ":" & ColLetter3 & lastRowWTH)

    Call setCellBorders(rng1)
End Sub
```

```
Function returnLabel(num1 As Long) As String

    Dim ColumnLetter As String

    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, num1).Address, "$")(1)

    returnLabel = ColumnLetter

End Function
```

The above function returns blank and varTest has nothing after the execution. If I do the line by line execution, I see that test1 in function is not 'Null'.
If I break the execution and probe the variables I see "test1 =" only as per the screen shot below. And this is breaking my code.

Strangely, If I call the function from 'Immediate Window', it returns the expected value.

Things I have already done:

- I have tested in a fresh file using simple code as above.
- Tested in different PC and the same code is working fine with same version of Windows 10 & Office 365.
- Updated / Re-installed MS Office 365
- Restarted the PC
- If the return value is a single character like "A", the code is working fine.

Failed to understand the reason here. Any help is appreciated.

[image: ScreenShot of the VBA Code Execution]

**UPDATE1**
I tried it on a fresh file while the code above worked, but the main code is having a new similar problem. This has started happening just now. It's not assigning a string value to the variable. See the attached screenshot.[Screenshot of the VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orPhN.png). I am assuming there is some problem with system or some virus.

Comment: `Function test1(num1 As Long) As Long` if you want to retrieve a number (long integer).

Comment: Use declarations... will ensure you're saving the type you want.

Comment: For me, using the code in your picture (with the `Debug.Print`), the immediate window shows `A` as I would expect. I think you need to clarify if you are expecting `test1` to act as an array or if the issue is the intellisense not showing the value when hovering (as seems to be happening in the picture).

Comment: Seems like you might want to just set up an [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement#remarks)

Comment: It does seem odd. Don't know what is behind what you are seeing. I am not able to replicate it.

Comment: You need more `Option Explicit` in your life =)

Comment: I have updated the sample code and description of the question. Please see again. Its not that I wanted to have two values returned. 'Code is working fine as expected in other PC with same windows and Excel'. My problem is that the code is not returning anything in VBA only on my PC.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, it's odd and even I am not able to replicate it in my other PC.

Comment: If there anything specific about the versions of Office, or the regional settings, which might be different?  At the end of the day, this may not be replicatable (sp?) by others trying to help and thus could be difficult to diagnose via SO...

Comment: VBA needs certain DLLs to run properly (the default references when you look at the project references under `tools` in the VBA editor). It sounds to me like the main VBA interpreter DLL has somehow become corrupt. Perhaps an office reinstall wouldn't automatically reinstall such DLLs since the installer might simply check if such files already exist and only install them if not. As a test -- what happens if you use similar code in Word VBA?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks John, that's a good pointer. But if you see my updated question now, the problem has moved to somewhere else and the previous is probably solved. Now it's not assigning a value to a variable. But yes again, some kind of corruption may have occurred. I may need to do a clean re-install of the office.

Comment: In any event, I am voting to close the question as off-topic since it is impossible to reproduce. Not even you are able to reproduce it on another machine. Good luck with solving it.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to have a function, that an array, this is possible with the following code:

```
Function Test1() As Variant
    ReDim result(2)
    result(0) = "AJ"
    result(1) = "A"
    Test1 = result
End Function

Sub Main()

    Dim varTest As Variant
    varTest = Test1(0)
    Debug.Print varTest
    varTest = Test1(1)
    Debug.Print varTest

End Sub
```

[image]

It is questionable why would it be needed, but as a "test-exercise" it is ok.

Comment: Was finishing up my answer and saw ours are about damn near identical.  In looking at what you had, I was a bit surprised that you could `redim result(2)` without having dimensioned it in the first place.  Will have to look into that, as I would have expected `dim result(2) as variant`.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue. If you look at OP's screenshot, it is rather odd (when I put a breakpoint where they do, I see `test1 = "AJ"` rather than the `test1 = ` which they show). Seems like their project might be corrupt in some way.

Comment: @JohnColeman I see what you're getting at now (just after posting my answer).  I also get `test = ` when I hover over the variable while it's equal to `AJ` (in Office 365).  The value pulls through properly though.

Comment: Would `varTest = Test1` be a better call, then just using `varTest` as the return is the array?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have udpated the code and comments to clarify my problem better. Problem is not with the code as it is working fine on other PC. It's not working as expected on one of my PCs, and for that please refer to screenshot.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The value pulls through properly if I call the function in immediate window. But if I call the function through any sub, I get a blank. I have also tested if the variable in function IsNull during execution, and strangely it's not NULL. Also, if the return value is only one character "A", the code works fine. And importantly this is happening only on one of the PC. I have repaired and reinstalled the MS-Office.

Answer (score 0):

Going to put my comments into an answer to consolidate and add more explanation.

Pointing out some errors in the code before correcting:

```
Function test1(num1) 'declare `as variant` to ensure you're returning an array
    test1 = "AJ"  'this appears to be saving a single string to var test1
    test1 = "A"  'you are now overwriting the above string
End function

Sub test()
    varTest = test1(1) 'you have a single string from the function and arrays start at 0, not 1
End sub
```

You would want to specify the place in the array, after declaring an array, within your function such that:

```
Function test1() As Variant
    Dim arr(2) As Variant 'added array because test1 = BLAH is the final output in a function
    arr(0) = "AJ"  'added (1) to call location in array
    arr(1) = "A"  'added (2) to call location in array
    test1 = arr
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim varTest As Variant
    varTest = test1(0) 'outputs "AJ" in immediate window
    Debug.Print varTest
End Sub
```

Now you can `debug.print` your array values, or set to `varTest` based on the location in the array.

---

**Edit:**  Tested after my consolidating comments and recognized that there was not an actual output for `test1` as an array at the end of the function, so had to go back and add a second array to set `test =` allowing an array output from a function.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, my problem is not the logic or working of the function but something else. Please go through my comments in questions and other answers to understand what issue I am facing.

Comment: @PulkitJain In reading the other comments, and specifically seeing John Coleman's comments on possible corruption or even a phantom bug, I would wonder if on a rudimentary point, if you were to fully declare and test the fully-declared code on the specific computer, would it run?  Whether or not it runs does not determine *why* the current issue is happening, but would at least give a path forward.

Comment: I did as you asked, and while it worked on a fresh file. My original file is having another similar problem now which was not there before. The simple statement like sheetName = "WTH" is assigning a blank value to the variable. I can attach a screenshot if required.

Comment: @PulkitJain is it possible to post, as an edit to your question, some of the actual code being used?  your `sheetname="WTH"` isn't there, which means we're slipping from original scope.  A screenshot on the post, along with more of the actual code, will help in understanding the issue(s).  Note that screenshots of code are less useful than posted code snippits.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see the code now with reference to second screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running as it should.

The `test1` function assigns the value *AJ* to the `test1` variable, and then it assigns the value *A* to the `test1` variable.
You could assign the value *50* in your `test` procedure and it will return *A*.

I think this is the code you're after:

```
Function test1(num1) As String

'    Dim MyArray As Variant
'    MyArray = Array("AJ", "A")

'OR

    Dim MyArray(0 To 1)
    MyArray(0) = "AJ"
    MyArray(1) = "A"

    If num1 >= LBound(MyArray) And num1 <= UBound(MyArray) Then
        test1 = MyArray(num1)
    Else
        test1 = "Item not here"
    End If

End Function

    Sub test()

        Dim varTest As String

        'Return the second item in the array from the function.
        varTest = test1(1)
        MsgBox varTest

        'Return the first item in the array from the function.
        varTest = test1(0)
        MsgBox varTest

        'Returns "subscript out of range" error as array is only 2 elements in size (0 and 1).
        'The error is dealt with in the function using the IF....ELSE...END IF block and returns
        '"Item not here" instead.
        varTest = test1(2)
        MsgBox varTest

    End Sub
```

Comment: "Your code is running as it should." -- only their code is *not* running as it should. There code was printing nothing rather than "A". They are describing a phantom bug in which the expected value is not returned on their machine

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought it was just the screen-tip not showing the value.  From what I can see the immediate window will return a result as `?test1(1)` will print out the result.  The `test` procedure doesn't have anything to display the result after it's executed.

Comment: "Return the {first/second} item in the array from the function" ...if the `(1)` or `(0)` is an array subscript, then where's the `num` argument?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using declaring the variables even when option explicit is not used.

The old code runs without throwing errors even when the variable is not declared and option explicit is also not used. But, for some reasons, it doesn't read / write undeclared variables as expected.

Now as per @cyril suggestion, I declared the variables being used and run the code. This time code ran as expected.

This happened for multiple of variables and at different stages in the code.